# Facing the issue "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Programming\REST_API\node_modules\nodemon\lib'"

Tags: reactjs, webpack-5

I've been working on a new MERN App using Redux and this is my first time working with ReactJS, Webpack and other utilities. I've been facing this error constantly

Here's the exact error

> ! ERROR in ../node_modules/nodemon/lib/monitor/run.js 5:19-43
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Programming\REST_API\node_modules\nodemon\lib\monitor'
> ERROR in ../node_modules/nodemon/lib/spawn.js 5:14-44
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Programming\REST_API\node_modules\nodemon\lib'
> ERROR in ../node_modules/nodemon/lib/version.js 5:11-40
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Programming\REST_API\node_modules\nodemon\lib'
> ERROR in ../node_modules/pstree.remy/lib/index.js 1:13-42
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Programming\REST_API\node_modules\pstree.remy\lib'
> ERROR in ../node_modules/pstree.remy/lib/tree.js 1:14-44
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Programming\REST_API\node_modules\pstree.remy\lib'
> ERROR in ../node_modules/pstree.remy/lib/utils.js 1:14-44
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Programming\REST_API\node_modules\pstree.remy\lib'

[Unexpected Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICaHc.png)

I've tried using [react-app-rewired](/questions/tagged/react-app-rewired) to reconfigure my webpack but it led to no good.
I've also added a [fallback](/questions/tagged/fallback) to the [react-scripts](/questions/tagged/react-scripts) file inside the [tag:node_modules] folder and edited the [webpack.config.js](/questions/tagged/webpack.config.js) file and added the following code inside [resolve](/questions/tagged/resolve)

The [fallback](/questions/tagged/fallback)code:

```
fallback: {
    fs: false,
    child_process: false,
    path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
    util: require.resolve("util/"),
  },
```

Here's my current package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.21.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build-css": "tailwindcss build src/style.css -o public/style.css"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "child-process": false
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "child-process": "^1.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.70.0",
    "sass-loader": "^14.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "webpack": "^5.90.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

Please help me with this issue